# Using std::cin to read from pipe after dup2()

Tags: c++, c, linux, pipe

I'm just trying to write a simple loopback function that runs in a child process after pipes have been set up and duplicated to stdin and stdout with dup2().  But the loopback hangs at the point it tries to read from the pipe.  The write end of the pipe -- in the parent process -- is a C function that uses fputs().  I know that the parent process works because if the child loopback function is replaced with another that uses read() in C it works.

Once I have got this working I'll be able to replace the loopback function with exec() and I'll expect that to work with programmes written in C++.

There are lots of questions similar to this, but solutions like calling setvbuf() do not work for me (you can see that I do call it in the parent loopback function).  And other questioners use read() directly on the pipe file descriptor (and that works when I do it -- but I want to test this with std::cin in C++).

So the main function looks like this: -

```
int pipeIn[2];  // To be read by child process
int pipeOut[2]; // To be written by child process

#define PARENT_TO_CHILD_READ_END  pipeIn[0]
#define PARENT_TO_CHILD_WRITE_END pipeIn[1]
#define CHILD_TO_PARENT_READ_END  pipeOut[0]
#define CHILD_TO_PARENT_WRITE_END pipeOut[1]

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pipe(pipeIn);
    pipe(pipeOut);

    pid_t hijo = fork();

    if (hijo == 0) {
        // CHILD
        dup2(PARENT_TO_CHILD_READ_END, STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(CHILD_TO_PARENT_WRITE_END, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(PARENT_TO_CHILD_READ_END);
        close(CHILD_TO_PARENT_WRITE_END);
        close(PARENT_TO_CHILD_WRITE_END);
        close(CHILD_TO_PARENT_READ_END);

        Child_plusplus_Loopback();

    } else if (hijo == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    } else {
        // PARENT
        close(PARENT_TO_CHILD_READ_END);
        close(CHILD_TO_PARENT_WRITE_END);

        Parent_FILE_Loopback(
                PARENT_TO_CHILD_WRITE_END,
                CHILD_TO_PARENT_READ_END);

        close(PARENT_TO_CHILD_WRITE_END);
        close(CHILD_TO_PARENT_READ_END);
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the loopback functions look like this: -

```
void
Parent_FILE_Loopback(const int outPipe, const int inPipe) {
    FILE * toChild   = fdopen(outPipe, "w");
    FILE * fromChild = fdopen(inPipe, "r");
    setvbuf(toChild, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    fputs("Hello", toChild);

    const size_t bufferSize(256);
    char         buffer[ bufferSize ];

    fgets(buffer, bufferSize, fromChild);

    printf("PARENT : %s\n\n", buffer);
}

void
Child_plusplus_Loopback(void) {
    string buffer;

    cin >> buffer; // this hangs

    string message("CHILD : ");
    message += buffer;

    cout << message;
}
```

The output from strace -f looks like this: -

```
clone(Process 6989 attached (waiting for parent)
Process 6989 resumed (parent 6988 ready)
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb74e5768) = 6989
[pid  6989] dup2(3, 0 <unfinished ...>
[pid  6988] close(3)                    = 0
[pid  6989] <... dup2 resumed> )        = 0
[pid  6988] close(6 <unfinished ...>
[pid  6989] dup2(6, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid  6988] <... close resumed> )       = 0
[pid  6989] <... dup2 resumed> )        = 1
[pid  6988] fcntl64(4, F_GETFL <unfinished ...>
[pid  6989] close(3 <unfinished ...>
[pid  6988] <... fcntl64 resumed> )     = 0x1 (flags O_WRONLY)
[pid  6989] <... close resumed> )       = 0
[pid  6989] close(6 <unfinished ...>
[pid  6988] brk(0 <unfinished ...>
[pid  6989] <... close resumed> )       = 0
[pid  6988] <... brk resumed> )         = 0x848f000
[pid  6989] close(4 <unfinished ...>
[pid  6988] brk(0x84b0000 <unfinished ...>
[pid  6989] <... close resumed> )       = 0
[pid  6988] <... brk resumed> )         = 0x84b0000
[pid  6989] close(5)                    = 0
[pid  6988] fstat64(4,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  6989] fstat64(0,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  6988] <... fstat64 resumed> {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  6989] <... fstat64 resumed> {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  6988] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0 <unfinished ...>
[pid  6989] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0 <unfinished ...>
[pid  6988] <... mmap2 resumed> )       = 0xb77d3000
[pid  6989] <... mmap2 resumed> )       = 0xb77d3000
[pid  6988] _llseek(4, 0,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  6989] read(0,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  6988] <... _llseek resumed> 0xbfefde40, SEEK_CUR) = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
[pid  6988] fcntl64(5, F_GETFL)         = 0 (flags O_RDONLY)
[pid  6988] fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  6988] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77d2000
[pid  6988] _llseek(5, 0, 0xbfefde40, SEEK_CUR) = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
[pid  6988] munmap(0xb77d3000, 4096)    = 0
[pid  6988] write(4, "Hello", 5)        = 5
[pid  6989] <... read resumed> "Hello", 4096) = 5
[pid  6988] read(5,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  6989] brk(0)                      = 0x848f000
[pid  6989] brk(0x84b0000)              = 0x84b0000
[pid  6989] read(0, 0xb77d3000, 4096)   = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
[pid  6988] <... read resumed> 0xb77d2000, 4096) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
[pid  6989] --- SIGWINCH (Window changed) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid  6988] --- SIGWINCH (Window changed) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid  6989] read(0,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  6988] read(5,
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reads from `std::cin` (or a `FILE*`) will normally be buffered,
which means that the call to `read()` will request some large number of
bytes.  The system arranges for a read from the console to return even
if less bytes have been read, but this doesn't hold for a read from a
pipe; the `read` called to fill the buffer will only return if the
buffer is filled or the write side of the pipe has been closed.

You can control the buffering somewhat, by calling `std::cin.setbuf`,
but this can be tricky; normally, it should be done before the first
input from `std::cin`.  And if you are inputting using `>>` to a string,
`std::cin` will continue calling `read` until it sees white space (or an
end of file).

EDIT:

It's still not really clear what you're trying to do.  If you need a
message based protocol, then you'll need something more than just pipes
and iostream; both of these are stream oriented, not message oriented.

The usual way I've handled this in the past it by writing the length of
the message (say as a four byte integer), followed by the message.  This
is fairly simple if there is only one reader and one writer on the pipe;
with more writers, you have to ensure that each write of the length plus
the message is atomic, and it cannot really be done if there are several
readers—you'll need a separate pipe for each reader.  For textual
formatting, you can use `std::ostringstream` and `std::istringstream`;
to write, convert the data in the `std::ostringstream` to a string, and
then:

```
void
writeOneMessage( int fd, std::string const& message )
{
    std::size_t size = message.size();
    char sizeBuffer[4] = 
    {
        (size >> 24) & 0xFF,
        (size >> 16) & 0xFF,
        (size >>  8) & 0xFF,
        (size      ) & 0xFF
    }
    write( fd, sizeBuffer, 4 );
    write( fd, message.data(), message.size() );
}
```

Reading is considerably more complicated, since there a number of
additional error condition you have to check for:

```
std::string
readOneMessage( int fd )
{
    char sizeBuffer[4];
    if ( read( fd, sizeBuffer, 4 ) != 4 ) {
        //  Really too simple: if you read 0, it's end of file
        //  if you read anythong other than 0 or 4, it's a serious
        //  error.
    }
    size_t size = ((sizeBuffer[0] & 0xFF) << 24)
                | ((sizeBuffer[1] & 0xFF) << 16)
                | ((sizeBuffer[2] & 0xFF) <<  8)
                | ((sizeBuffer[3] & 0xFF)      );
    std::string message( size );
    if ( read( fd, &message[0], size ) != size ) {
        //  Can only be a format error...
    }
    return message;
}
```

Again, once you've read the message, you can use it to construct an
`std::istringstream`, and parse it like you want.

This is really the only way you can reliably implement a message based
protocol with a pipe; the alternative would be to write a `'\0'`
terminated string for each message, and read byte by byte until you find
the `'\0'`.  (In practice, using `FILE*`, setting all of the streams to
line buffered, will often work most of the time, provided the messages
are small enough, but it's not really guaranteed, nor reliable.)

Comment: Does this mean that the pipe approach is the wrong one altogether?  I don't want to close the pipe each time something is written, because it will need to be created again.   If these sorts of pipes are not the way to do, can you suggest something else, and I'll try it.

Comment: Your description of the behavior of read(2) doesn't seem to match up with its specifications.  When that function is called on a file descriptor not set for non-blocking mode, it is required to block until at least one byte is transferred or EOF is detected, but it is by no means required to read the full number of bytes specified before returning.

Comment: Well, in that case my solution with read() is non-portable.  However, even if it worked by accident it did show (luckily) that the parent loopback function worked.  And, in fact, that is all it was meant to do.  I really want to concentrate on std::cin.  Would I be right in thinking that a call to pubsetbuf(nullptr,0) -- I've just found it in Josuttis -- would not survive a call to exec()?

Comment: @Alex, I am writing an answer right now that may clarify things a bit.  There is nothing inherently non-portable with what you're doing -- it's just not quite right.

Comment: @JohnBollinger There's a generic specification of `read`, which is very open, to allow it to support all sorts of devices, and there are the requirements of `pipe`.  Writes to a `pipe` up to a certain size are required to be atomic, and in practice, if there is a `read` of that size open, it will also be serviced atomically.  But you're right that in general,   pipes (nor TCP sockets) don't directly support a message based protocol.

Comment: @JamesKanze, Yes, writes to a pipe up to a certain size are atomic.  Yes, it is reasonable to expect that a `read()` requesting less than or equal to the number of bytes already available from a pipe will transfer that full number of bytes, unless it is interrupted by a signal (though I find no *requirement* for that, not even a pipe-specific one).  But no, I find no support whatever for the proposition that a `read()` on any kind of file descriptor should be expected to block until it can transfer the full number of bytes requested.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If you consider how a pipe is implemented in the kernel... The read process will either see 0 bytes, or the byte count of the full read.  (Of course, if the writer manages to write two messages before the reader is active, the byte count in the pipe will go from 0 to the number of bytes in both messages.  Pipes are not message based.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, you emphasized that `std::cin` would attempt to read some large number of bytes, claiming that the `read()` would block until the read buffer was *filled* or the write side of the pipe was closed.  The `read()` blocking supposedly explained the OP's stall.  Perhaps I'm reading more into that than you intended, but it is empirically untrue that `std::cin <<` was waiting for a full buffer, as writing just one more byte (a newline) resolved the issue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Now you've got me confused; it's been a while since I last wrote code which communicated via pipes.  So I looked it up: basically, if `O_NONBLOCK` isn't set, `read` will block until _some_ data is available; so reading through `istream` should work as you describe.  You still need to ensure a flush when writing, of course.

Comment: And finally, having reverified the Posix standard, I think that John's answer is better for this specific case.  (I won't delete mine, because I think it is useful in more general cases.)

Answer (score 0):

Reading from `std::cin` will often be *line* buffered.  This means that the `>>` operator does not return until a newline has been read or the end of the stream is reached.  Even if `std::cin` happened not to be buffered in your case, the stream must keep trying to read until it sees the end of the string, which happens at whitespace or the end of the stream (*not* necessarily at the end of the currently-available bytes).  In any case, you do not need to worry about the details of the underlying `read()` calls.  That's the responsibility of your C++ library implementation.

Your server writes the five characters of "Hello" to the pipe, but `fputs()` does not automatically follow them with a newline (unlike `puts()`) or anything else.  If you want a newline to be sent -- to interoperate well with line buffering on the reading side -- then you must send it explicitly:

```
fputs("Hello\n", toChild);
```

or

```
fputs("Hello", toChild);
fputc('\n', toChild);
```

Even if the reading side were unbuffered, you would need to send at least a space or tab character so that the reader can recognize the end of the string.  As long as you need to do that anyway, you're better off using a newline.

Any way around, if the output stream were buffered then you might want to follow that up with an `fflush(toChild)`, but inasmuch as you are explicitly making it unbuffered (not necessarily a wise choice), the above should be enough to make the client's read return.

Do note that an analogous consideration applies to the message sent back to the parent by the child: `fgets()` reads up to a newline or EOF, and it doesn't look like the child is terminating its reply message with a newline.  Or flushing.

Comment: Thanks that works.  '\n' did the trick.  And if I remove the setvbuf() line, then I need fflush() as you mentioned.

Comment: There is no line buffering on iostreams, at least not according to the C++ standard.  (Some implementations _do_ forward to `FILE*` functions, which in turn may be line buffered.  It's the easiest way to support `sync_with_stdio`.  It's not something I would count on, however.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: fair enough.  I've modified my answer a bit.  In particular, I've emphasized what I now realize is the essential issue, which is not line buffering *per se*, but rather having some kind of whitespace after the string so that the stream recognizes its end.

Comment: Yes.  On input, you need something to cause `<<` to return.  On output, you need a flush.

Answer (score 0):

After a proper setup of file descriptors you need a defined protocol for the communication.

A pipe using std::cout/std::cin:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int parent_pipe[2];
int child_pipe[2];

void parent_loop() {
    std::cout << "Hello Child" << ' ' << "Disconnect" << std::endl;
    std::string receive("Parent Receives: ");
    while(true) {
        std::string buffer;
        if( ! (std::cin >> buffer) || buffer == "Disconnect")
            break;
        receive += buffer;
    }
    std::cout << "Disconnect";
    std::cerr << receive << std::endl;
}

void child_loop() {
    std::string receive(" Child Receives: ");
    while( true) {
        std::string buffer;
        if( ! (std::cin >> buffer) || buffer == "Disconnect")
            break;
        receive += buffer;
    }
    std::cout << "Hello Parent" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Disconnect" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << receive << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pipe(parent_pipe);
    pipe(child_pipe);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if (pid) {
        // Parent
        if((dup2(child_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1)
        || (dup2(parent_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1))
        {
            std::cerr << "Setup Failure\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        close(child_pipe[1]);
        close(parent_pipe[0]);

        parent_loop();

        close(child_pipe[0]);
        close(parent_pipe[1]);
    }
    else {
        // Child
        if((dup2(parent_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1)
        || (dup2(child_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1))
        {
            std::cerr << "Setup Failure\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        close(parent_pipe[1]);
        close(child_pipe[0]);

        child_loop();

        close(parent_pipe[0]);
        close(child_pipe[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please notice the use of `std::endl` to put a delimiter into the stream and flush the stream.
If you want unformatted IO you might use read and write functions, instead (A child might read chunks written by a parent until EOF).
Note: Logging and error messages go to std::cerr (STDERR_FILENO)

Output:

```
 Child Receives: HelloChild
Parent Receives: HelloParent
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have paid more attention to message delineation at the transmit end and what std::cin looks for.